# Writing comma delimited string to serial port from floating point variables

Tags: c, string, floating-point, serial-port, concatenation

I am parsing a string that has 3 values in it, comma separated. I am currently using sscanf for this, which works just fine. What I am trying to do is to manipulate on of these values after parsing the string and concatenate my results back into the same format that I received it in and write it back to the serial port after each time I read and manipulate the string. I think the problem that I am running into is that I declare the variable as a float when being parsed, and am wondering how I can put the floats back together to write to a serial port. I am also having the problem of the variables actually writing to the buffer and sending out, but that is a different story. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Here is a sample of what I have:

```
    do {
                struct timeval timeout = {0,299500};
                char c;
                fd_set fds;
                int ret1, ret2;
                //Zero file descriptor set, then append all types.
                FD_ZERO(&fds);
                FD_SET(cmp_fd, &fds);
                FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO, &fds);
                ret1 = select(FD_SETSIZE, &fds, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
                if (ret1 == -1)
                  {
                        perror("select");
                        need_exit = 1;
                  }
                 else if (ret1 > 0)
                         {
                         if (FD_ISSET(cmp_fd, &fds))
                                {
                                 do {ret2 = read(cmp_fd, &c, 1);}
                                 while ((ret2 < 0 && errno == EINTR));
                                 if (ret2 == 1)
                                        {
                                        data_str[cmp_ind] = c;
                                        cmp_ind++;

                                        if(c == '\n')
                                                {
                                                float press, temp, cond;
                                                char strn;

      int asdf = sscanf(data_str,"%f,%f,%f", &press, &temp, &cond);
                                        strn = ("%f,%f, %f", press, temp, cond);

char ppri[3]
ppri[1]= [press+1.3,temp,cond];
ppri[2] = temp;
ppri[3] = cond;
printf("%f",ppri);

write(cmp_fd,ppri,sizeof(ppri));    /* <-- This is what I am trying to do*/
                       /*needed output is: "#####.##,#####.##, #####.##" */ 
                                                bzero(data_str,100);
                                                cmp_ind = 0;
                                                printf("\r\n");

                                                }
                                        }
                              else if(ret2 == -1)
                                         {
                                           perror("read");
                                           need_exit = 1;
                                         }
                              }
                if(FD_ISSET(STDIN_FILENO, &fds))
                        {
                        do {ret2 = read(STDIN_FILENO, &c, 1);}
                        while (ret2 < 0 && errno == EINTR);
                                if(ret2 == 1)
                                        {
                                        if(c == '\x01') {
                                                need_exit = -1;
                                        }
                        }
        }
}

}
 while (!need_exit);
```

Comment: Instead of tagging the question with things like concatenation, the programming languages would be a nice addition. Because that will make your question appear on some people's radar.  ;o)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int asdf = sscanf(data_str,"%f,%f,%f", &press, &temp, &cond);
strn = ("%f,%f, %f", press, temp, cond);
```

i think above you probably wanted to form a string with all the three float variables but, this is actually storing the `cond` float value converted to a character in `strn`

```
char ppri[3]
```

`ppri` is an array of 3 characters, which literally cannot store three float values after converting them into string, unless each float is a single digit integer. but still, you have no space to put three commas in that also.

```
ppri[1]= [press+1.3,temp,cond];
```

this line will not compile at any cost, i dont know how it compiles for you.

```
ppri[2] = temp;
ppri[3] = cond;
```

declared char array of size 3 and you cannot access `ppri[3]`, array index starts with 0.

```
printf("%f",ppri);
```

since ppri is an array, ppri store the address of the first char.

```
write(cmp_fd,ppri,sizeof(ppri));
```

this will write 3 characters in the file pointed by the fd.

I am not sure what you are trying to do in these part of the code, this is my initial observation, you can see other mistakes in the code, try fixing them.

but anyhow if you want to parse float separated by comma, then you could use,

```
float f1, f2, f2;
// read float values from string,
sscanf(data_str,"%f,%f,%f",&f1,&f2,&f3);
// modify the float value
f1 += 10;
// form the modified string again.
sprintf(data_str,"%f,%f,%f",f1,f2,f3);
```

and write back the `data_str`

Comment: Sridhar, thank you this was very helpful and solved quite a few of the problems that I was having! The three problems that I still have are that for some reason sprint will not output anything for me but printf will; before I implement the f1 += 10, my f1 value is already off by a factor of 10 (could be something that is wrong in my code); lastly, implementing f1 += 10 does not seem to change the value of f1 (I cant seem to change it by setting it equal to a different value either).

Comment: Sridhar, following up on the last comment that I left; I currently am getting the value of f1 to change, sprintf is now working, but for some reason I am still off by a factor of 10 with f1. This does not matter though as I will be manually inputting the value to something user defined and not adding/subtracting to it. Thanks for the help with this!